# got Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase. error even though i already called it

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got 'Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase' error even though I already called it in the 'Appdelegate.swift'.[This is my app delegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzskq.jpg)

Comment: Please paste your code into the question

Comment: If you think My answer is correct, please give me 'best answer' . Thank you :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***First Solution***:

If you use `FIRDatabase.database().reference()` in your ViewController, please share the code with us. If you use something like this:

```
var db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

before viewDidLoad, you can get this error. Better make this:

```
var db: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
```

In this way, even if configure() is in finishLaunchingWithOptions, the app won't crash.

***Second solution***:

In `AppDelegate.swift` just add this lines of code:

```
override init() {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

When the app launch, it will go to `init()` method and will configure **FireBase** before everything else.

Comment: Second solution there causes a crash for me - says that 'Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database'

Comment: Yeah, change FIRApp.configure() to FirebaseApp.configure() . My answer was for older version. Sorry

Comment: Second solution worked for me. Thanks  Altimir Antonov

Comment: Thank You So much var db: FIRDatabaseReference! it's works for me you save my day Altimir Antonov