# Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i try Auth user to Firebase, is ok but when i try to write database user's email adress, getting error.

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sifreField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sifre1Field: UITextField!

    var ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func kayitBtn(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if(sifreField.text != sifre1Field.text)
        {
            print("****error****")
        }
        else if ( !(emailField.text?.isEmpty)! || !(sifreField.text?.isEmpty)! || !(sifre1Field.text?.isEmpty)! )
        {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: sifreField.text!) { (user, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print ("***error***")
                }
                else if ( !(self.emailField.text?.isEmpty)! || !(self.sifreField.text?.isEmpty)!  || !(self.sifre1Field.text?.isEmpty)! )
                {
                    self.ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["email": self.emailField.text!])
                    print("database ok")
                }
        }
        }
    }

}
```

my AppDelegate.swift (added `import Firebase` and FirebaseApp.configure() in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

And my console error:

[image]

what am i supposed to do now? thanks for everything.

Comment: in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from your app delegate call `FIRapp.configure()`

Comment: @Lamar yes because firebase wants to me add `import Firebase` and add `FirebaseApp.configure()` code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: yes, if I remember this method is loading the google plist which contains your db path from firebase. Did you do that, did you find another issue ?

Comment: @Lamar yes, you mean GoogleService-Info.plist. I added already but i confuse. Must i delete default Info.plist? didnt remember :D i hope im not retard

Comment: You don't need to delete anything, you just need to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` into your project, and install firebase pod into your project. then call `FIRapp.configure()` which will load your google plist into your app, so when you call `Database.database().reference`it will have the current database path from your firebase app

Comment: @Lamar it's my files https://i.imgur.com/vMO5glD.png

Comment: if you want to you can post your code into a github repo then share the link so we could see what is the real issue lol :)

Comment: @Lamar oh that was hard :/

Comment: I am not quite following now.... let's started again did you install firebase via pod, then did you  add the google plist into your project ... did you call configure() method in your appDelegate? if yes to all these questions what is the result do you still have the same result ?

Comment: @Lamar Yes, i installed firebase via pod. yes i added google plist in my project. yes i called `FirebaseApp.configure()` in appDelegate. and yes still have same problem. i added my appdelegate on my question.

Comment: check to see if your `GoogleService-Info.plist` contains all the information, mostly DATABASE_URL should not be empty

Comment: @Lamar all ok. if it was already a problem plist , i could not did Auth. when try auth user email its ok but cant write user email in database. and my database_url is not empty

Comment: @Lamar  solved problem mate with this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168616/got-must-call-firapp-configure-before-using-firdatabase-error-even-though-i-a   i think it's firebase bug. thanks for everything

Comment: The Answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168616/got-must-call-firapp-configure-before-using-firdatabase-error-even-though-i-a

Answer (score 6):

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
```

This will solve your problem and the app won't crash.